Tiered usage based subscription billed at the beginning of each month
We're currently developing a system that will allow users to execute procedures, with each procedure costing a certain amount of credits. At the end of the month we charge based on the amount of credits consumed, multiplied by some factor (e.g. 0.001$ per credit). However, we also need to charge a monthly flat fee for the usage of our service. So the plans look something like this:

FREE) Free usage of 1000 credits, after which the user needs to
upgrade

BASIC) Flat fee 10$, then the user can use up to 10000 credits, after
that they need to pay 0.001$ per spent credit

PREMIUM) Flat fee 50$, then the user can use up to 100000 credits,
after that they need to pay 0.001$ per spent credit


Stripe allows us to define this type of billing model pretty easily, however the issue is the timing of the billing. The flat fee is charged at the beginning of the subscription by default, and there is no easy way to change this. Proration also doesn't work for usage based billing, e.g. if the user signs up for premium plan on 25th they will be billed for the full amount of 50$ dollars immediately + any overage usage at the end of the month.
I've spent a lot of time to see how this can be reconfigured to bill everything at the end of the month, with flat amount proportional to the subscription date, but it cannot be done in a straightforward way.
One way to define it that would work for me is defining the flat fee as usage as well, and setting this usage depending on the subscription start date. For example:

User starts on 15th with PREMIUM, set usage as 25$
Have a routine that sets usage to 50$ at the beginning of each month

However this seems to be pretty convoluted for a use case that I would except to be easily achievable out of the box.
Is there a better way to do what I want?

If the critical part blocking you is the one-time fee being charged at the beginning of the period, then you can instead remove that item from the subscription and instead add it as a one-time item to the usage generated invoice at the end of the period. Following the creation of the invoice, there's a one-hour period before finalization where you can use the API to add additional items.

Thanks @jonathan-steele, so the approach would be to listen for invoice.created, check how much fee must be added, and then do it on a monthly basis as billing cycles close?

Yes, that should work. Let me know how you get on!
